# How do I set attribute default values in sqlalchemy declarative?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy Declarative, how do I set up default values for columns, such that transient or pending object instances will have those default values? A short example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
  __tablename__ = "A"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  word = Column(String, default="adefault")

a = A()
print a.word
```

Naively, I would expect the output from this to be `adefault`. Of course, the output is actually `None`. Even when adding to a session, it stays`None` and only gets filled when I commit (or flush) the session, and re-read the instance value from the database.

Is there any way to set an attribute default without flushing the instance to the database? I tried investigating the `ColumnDefault` documentation, and there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to inspect the type/python value, so as to manually set it in a custom declarative baseclass.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14002631/6646912

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a constructor to your class and set the default value there.  The constructor doesn't run when the rows are loaded from the database so it is fine to do this.

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "A"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    word = Column(String)

    def __init__(self):
        self.word = "adefault"

a = A()
print a.word
```

There are examples of using `__init__` in similar ways in the [SA Docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping).

Comment: If you want to guarantee that an instance of `A` has a value for `word`, the constructor seems better than a default value in the column definition. Is there ever a case where you would need to have the default specified in both places?

Comment: The answer doesn't seem to work at all for me. It prints None and __init__ is never called.

Comment: It doesn't appear that  `__init__` on the declarative base is called for the actual model classes.