# How to apply Column defaults before a commit in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a declarative-base model:

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    money = Column(Integer, default=100)
```

and then I run

```
>>> u = User()
>>> u.money
None
```

How can I populate the defaults using sqlalchemy *without* writing anything to the database?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48097586/6646912

Comment: the question linked above answers this question. recommend checking it out

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The column default only applies to INSERT and UPDATE statements, and thus isn't being applied until you `.flush()` the session.

To see the same value on new instances before you flush, you need to apply the default when a new instance is being created; in the `__init__` method of the `User` object:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if 'money' not in kwargs:
             kwargs['money'] = self.__table__.c.money.default.arg
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    money = Column(Integer, default=100)
```

If no `money` attribute is being set, we add one directly based on the default configured for the column.

Note that the defaults are *SQL expressions*, not Python values, so you may have to map those to Python objects first. For example, a boolean field will have a default `'false'` or `'true'` string value, not a `False` or `True` Python boolean object.

Comment: So if I want to fill in all defaults of a more complex object, I have to iterate over all columns, see if it has a default and fill it into the respective attribute. Okay, I can code that up. I just wonder: This functionality must exist in sqlalchemy, because it needs it at insert/update time anyway. And I wonder, why it's not exposed to users.

Comment: @Elrond: Probably because the defaults are aimed at the SQL side; you can have non-static defaults that are expressed as SQL as well.

Comment: I like Martijn's solution, seems very complete.

I've always done it like this in the past, which might be a bit less code as you don't have to iterate over your columns.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384996/how-do-i-set-attribute-default-values-in-sqlalchemy-declarative/13390300#13390300

Comment: To get this to work for a Boolean field, I had to do this `kwargs['my_flag'] = ('true' == str(self.__table__.c.my_flag.server_default.arg))` because it sees the default as a text value ("false") instead of a boolean.

Comment: @JayK: yes, because as I stated in a previous comment: *the defaults are aimed at the SQL side*.

Comment: @YoloVoe: that listener utility is defined in a *third party library*, not in core SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I noticed it right after submitting :'(. Thanks for letting me know and my sincerest apologies for that.

Answer (score 7):

I have discovered a mechanism for populating some defaults automatically when an instance is created. I'm migrating from an in-house ORM that set defaults at instance creation, so I needed to preserve this behaviour and I didn't want to touch every model definition.

```
BaseModel = declarative_base()

class Base(BaseModel):
    __abstract__ = True

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for attr in self.__mapper__.column_attrs:
            if attr.key in kwargs:
                continue

            # TODO: Support more than one value in columns?
            assert len(attr.columns) == 1
            col = attr.columns[0]

            if col.default and not callable(col.default.arg):
                kwargs[attr.key] = col.default.arg

        super(Base, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

The major limitation is that only non-callable defaults are supported. Callable defaults and those that use a database query require an execution context that isn't available at instance creation time. Also, I have not discovered a case where `len(ColumnProperty.columns) != 1` but that isn't supported either.

Answer (score 2):

Since I need the default values not necessarily in constructor, but sometimes from other places, I came up with a function, that I added to my base Object class:

```
Base = declarative_base()
class ItemBase(Base):
    __abstract__ = True
    def _ensure_defaults(self):
        for column in self.__table__.c:
            if getattr(self, column.name) is None and column.default is not None and column.default.is_scalar:
                setattr(self, column.name, column.default.arg)
```

Which obviously does not work for callables. I could not figure out how to call it, and maybe it's for the better (feel like hacking the think already).

With this I can do something like:

```
class User(ItemBase):
    # ... inheritance, columns and stuff
    def __init__(self):
        self._ensure_defaults()
```

I can also call the method not in `__init__`, but also from other methods, in case I only need to rely on the values in special circumstances (which I ended up removing later, since it was too confusing). Still in some cases this might be more flexible than the solution of @JamesEmerton.