# SQLAlchemy: Output of default value is None

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm making a web app using Flask and SQLAlchemy. And what I want to do is to cone out the default value on web. But the output becomes None. The Column is like this.

```
n = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
```

I tried `server_default='0'` and `server_default=text('0')` as well but these outputs are also None.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002631/why-isnt-sqlalchemy-default-column-value-available-before-object-is-committed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default values are only set after an INSERT or UPDATE is issued, i.e. after your session is flushed to the db. If you're seeing `None` for the value of `yourobject.n` then I'm guessing you haven't committed your changes yet.

Test this again, but this time after you create an instance of your object, add it and commit it:

```
>>> instance = MyDBModel()
>>> instance.n is None
True
>>> db.session.add(instance)
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> instance.n is None
False
>>> print(instance.n)
0
```

If for some reason you need to apply column defaults *before* you flush your changes to the database, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791487/how-to-apply-column-defaults-before-a-commit-in-sqlalchemy) question which covers that topic.