# Why isn't SQLAlchemy default column value available before object is committed?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, default-value

Recently I figured out that SQLAlchemy's Column default doesn't work as I expect it to:

```
>>> Base = declarative_base()
>>> class TestModel(Base):
    ...     __tablename__ = 'tmodel'
...     id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
...     foo = sa.Column(sa.Integer, default=0)
...    
>>> tmodel_instance = TestModel()
>>> print tmodel_instance.foo
None
>>> session.add(tmodel_instance)
>>> print tmodel_instance.foo
None
>>> session.commit()
>>> print tmodel_instance.foo
0
```

I want `tmodel_instance.foo` to equal `0` right after object instantiation, but it seems that the default value is only used when executing `INSERT` command, and it really confuses me. Why would one prefer the  `default` over `server_default`? And how do I achieve what I want? Am I supposed to specify all default arguments in `__init__`? That seems to be code duplication: to change the default value I have to change it twice and maintain those values equality -- is there some way to avoid that?

Comment: +1 Agree. It doesn't make sense that the act of persisting an object will change it's attributes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `force_instant_defaults` listener from `sqlalchemy_utils` to change this behavior:

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import force_instant_defaults

force_instant_defaults()

class TestModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tmodel'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo = sa.Column(sa.Integer, default=0)

model = TestModel()
assert model.foo == 0
```

Answer (score 33):

one would prefer default over server default for one of four reasons:

1. you'd like to run a Python function, not a SQL function, for the default (or a SQL expression that needs some per-INSERT Python state also).
2. the default is part of a primary key column.  the ORM can't load a row back without the primary key, so server_default is generally not useful for a PK column when using the ORM.
3. the SQL expression you want to run isn't supported by the database as a "server default".
4. You're dealing with a schema you can't/don't want to change.

In this case, when you'd like "foo" to be "0" in your application independent of database operations, the choices are:

1. use `__init__()`.  It's python!
2. use events.

Here's `__init__()`:

```
class TestModel(Base):
   # ...

   def __init__(self):
       self.foo = 0
```

Here's events (specifically the [init event](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html?highlight=orm%20events#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents.init)):

```
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Foo, "init")
def init(target, args, kwargs):
    target.foo = 0
```

Comment: But why was sqlAlchemy models designed in this way: None instead of default value right after creation? That definitely confuses people which are used to other ORM libraries

Comment: the "default" is more often than not a SQL expression or a full blown server-side value.   It cannot be known until the INSERT takes place, or much less ideally if it were awkwardly pre-executed when the object is created (which itself degrades the value being a true "INSERT defaut").  therefore to make just one subset of core-level insert defaults act totally differently would be inconsistent.

Comment: It's weird though that `session.flush(model)` and `session.refresh(model)` still results in a `None` value, since flushing the session generates a primary key...

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `init` event to fill defaults. This event listener will do it:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect


def instant_defaults_listener(target, args, kwargs):
    for key, column in inspect(target.__class__).columns.items():
        if column.default is not None:
            if callable(column.default.arg):
                setattr(target, key, column.default.arg(target))
            else:
                setattr(target, key, column.default.arg)


event.listen(mapper, 'init', instant_defaults_listener)
```

Comment: This worked for a long time, but now I get an error: `sqlalchemy Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with * has an attribute '_supports_population' mapper`.  [Krassowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48097586/2223706) works for me.

Comment: Updated for loop is now
```
    for key, column in sa.inspect(target.__class__).columns.items():
        if (
            hasattr(column, 'default') and
            column.default is not None
        ):
            if callable(column.default.arg):
                kwargs[key] = column.default.arg(target)
            else:
                kwargs[key] = column.default.arg```