# SQLAlchemy column is None after commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Why is the column None after commit() the value is not None in the database.

```
text_data = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)
```

Using `bulk_save_objects(...)`

```
db.session.bulk_save_objects(data_models, return_defaults=True)
db.session.commit()
for dm in data_models:
   print("version", m.text_data) # None even though 1 in database
```

If I do include the column in the insert object the property is set.

```
data_model = DataModel(text_data=1, ...)
data_models.append(dm)
```

Comment: may you need to refresh the session to get the most last values from the db.

Comment: I get this error with refresh and it is after the commit: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Instance '<DataModel at 0x51135d0>' is not persistent within this Session

Comment: why vote to close

Comment: The error makes sense if you are trying to insert the raw values of which session has no clue. For it to work you may need to query back again and fetch the objects you need.

Comment: Voted to close this originally since you haven't provided a [mcve], but on the other hand this is answerable. Meanwhile read the warning in the docs carefully: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_save_objects

Comment: Also somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002631/why-isnt-sqlalchemy-default-column-value-available-before-object-is-committed

Comment: its confusing whats the point of return_defaults=True